# How do you determine which EFI System Partition the system booted from in Linux?

Tags: linux, uefi, bootable-media, efi

If a system has multiple disks with EFI System Partitions is it possible to determine which EFI System Partition was used to boot the system in Linux once the system is booted if they both boot the same kernel?

Comment: The UEFI entry uses the GUID/partUUID of the ESP. `lsblk -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,partuuid` and UEFI entries: `sudo efibootmgr -v` Your fstab should also show the mount of your ESP. `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: I was afraid that was the answer.  What happens if the ESP's share a UUID because it was cloned from one another?  Is there a way to translate the device path given by efibootmgr -v into a corresponding Linux device?  This particular embedded Linux system doesn't automatically mount the ESP hence my need to determine which one it booted from so I can mount it.

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/355310). For the record: [the same question on U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/664716/108618).

Comment: When there are duplicate UUID/GUID partitions, it may even be random which is mounted first. UEFI checks system & records the info onto the drive for the operating system. It then is often first come first served on which is first. If one drive is faster, it may normally be first. Backup both & delete one. You can normally use efibootmgr to add new entry if required. But embedded device may not fully support efibootmgr.

Answer (score 1):

Read the `BootCurrent` EFI variable, then read the `Boot####` variable that BootCurrent points to. It will show the path to the EFI application – which includes the partition's GPT GUID (note: not filesystem UUID).